# Jasmine - Getting "describe is not defined" when run the script using spectron

Tags: node.js, automation, electron, spectron

I have install spectron using the following command
 npm install -g spectron

but i am unable to run globally.
So I install locally as you said.
 have installed Jasmine and i have specified test scrips as jasmine in package.json

```
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')
var jasmine = require('jasmine')

describe('application launch', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.app = new Application({
        path: 'C:\\Users\\ramass11\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\ng-site-solutions\\ng-site-solutions.exe'
     })
    return this.app.start()
  })
})
```

If I run my script using the command node First.js, I am getting
"describe is not  defined"

I want to know why i am getting this error and whether the way i am importing the jasmine is right ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are missing the TypeScript definitions for Jasmine. Have you added `"@types/jasmine": "2.6.0"` to your package.json file under devDependencies?

If not run `npm install --save @types/jasmine`

Comment: TS definitions is just definitions, no functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should run your test with some kind of test runner (which defines `describe` and `it`), I would recommend `mocha` in this case.

```
npm install mocha --save-dev
node_modules/.bin/mocha First.js
```